# When is a transaction callback called?

Tags: mining, web3js, contract-invocation, confirmations

Is the callback of a myContractMethod.sendTransaction(/* ... */) called as soon as the the transaction is sent to the network or once it is mined?

**Related posts**

Here are some related references I found about this but there seems to be some contradicting information and I also suspect some of it might be deprecated given how much ethereum changes month to month:

- According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6731/should-callbacks-be-called-twice-from-both-mycontract-new-and-mycontract-myfunct) ,a .new() transaction is called twice (before and after mining) and other transactions are called once (but when?!)
- According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/how-can-i-program-my-dapp-to-tell-my-user-that-their-action-transaction-has-been), all callbacks are called twice (does not seem to be the case for me...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `sendTransaction`, the callback is only called once, immediately and you get the transaction hash.

You are correct, for `.new`, the callback is called twice, before and after mining, as the post says.  And I'll make a [comment on the second post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1188/how-can-i-program-my-dapp-to-tell-my-user-that-their-action-transaction-has-been#comment7184_1197) to clarify `sendTransaction` callback.

Comment: Can we accomplish that using events in solidity(transaction mined event) ?

Comment: @VivekSadh Question is unclear and you may want to post a new one. (Solidity and mining are fairly disconnected, and there's no transaction mined event in Solidity.)